# How to update the domain model object based on the domain model parameter passed to Edit action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action method to handle the HTTP-POST as follows.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie model)
    {
        var movie = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

        if (movie == null)
        {
            TempData["MESSAGE"] = "No movie with id = " + id + ".";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        // what method do I have to invoke here
        // to update the movie object based on the model parameter?
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Question: How to update `movie` based on `model` ?

**Edit 1**

Based on @lukled's solution, here is the final and working code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie model)
    {
        var movie = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

        if (movie == null)
        {
            TempData["MESSAGE"] = string.Format("There is no Movie with id = {0}.", movie.Id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var entry = db.Entry(movie);
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.Movies.ApplyCurrentValues(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You can also just copy values from model to movie:

```
movie.Title = model.Title;
movie.Director = model.Director;
db.SaveChanges();
```

OK. You are using Code First, so it will be probably:

```
var entry = context.Entry(movie);
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But I am not sure about it, because I don't have Code First installed. Taken from:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/30/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-5-working-with-property-values.aspx

Comment: @Lukled: EF 4 does not have `ApplyCurrentValue` method.

Comment: @Lukled: Your second option is already thought before posting this question. But it is tedious.

Comment: @Lukled: Error 1 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>' does not contain a definition for 'ApplyCurrentValue' and no extension method 'ApplyCurrentValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\MVC\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Controllers\MovieController.cs 92 23 MvcMovie

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
{

    if (movie == null)
    {
        TempData["MESSAGE"] = "No movie with id = " + id + ".";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(movie);

    // what method do I have to invoke here
    // to update the movie object based on the model parameter?

    db.Movie.AddObject(movie);
    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(movie, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: `AddObject` does not exist in EF 4.

Comment: @user596314 It exists in my version of EF4... I got that from my app code and I am definitely using EF4

Comment: I used EFCodeFirst and am new to EF. By the way, why did you add the movie to the context rather than modify the existing one?

Comment: One more, why did you remove the checking parts of my code? If the given id does not correspond to any record in the database, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
TryUpdateModel(movie)
```